# Callback on mdMenu close

Tags: angular-material

Lets say I have an app that can open menus, for example via `$mdOpenMenu($event)`.

My app needs to set a callback to get notified when a menu opens or closes.

How can I achieve it? I read the official documentation and I can't seem to find it.

I was looking for something like `md-on-remove` (used on `mdChips`), but it doesn't seem to be implemented for `mdMenu` ([issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7070)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$scope.$on("$mdMenuClose", function() { console.log("menu closing") });`

Comment: Thanks! It really solves the problem. Mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: FYI "mdMenuOpen" also exists as a scope event. "$mdMenuClose" fires before the menu is finished closing and is still visible. I wanted to reset the menu content on close, and doing this on "$mdMenuClose" caused the user to see the menu content change a split second before it disappeared. I moved the reset logic to the "mdMenuOpen" event, and that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
ng-click="$mdOpenMenu(); AppCtrl.closeMdMenu();"
```

AppCtrl

```
vm.closeMdMenu = function() { $mdMenu.hide(); };
```